# serializable transaction isolation lock

Tags: sql, sql-server, serialization, transaction-isolation

I have set a serializable transaction isolation lock for a transaction.But i am observing some results which are not expected.

My query is

```
update tabl1 set col2 = 10 where col1 > 10 and col1 < 20
```

Here col1 is primary key.Here rows with col1 having value  10,11,12....19,20 are locked for update/insert. In where condition i have given conditions as col1>10 and col1<20 but still rows having col1=10 and col1=20 gets locked.

If i give

```
update tabl1 set col2 = 10 where col1 => 10 and col1 <= 20
```

then rows with col2 having values from 9 to 21 gets locked.So why col1 having 9 and 21 gets locked here?

For the below query full table gets locked.Here col3 is a non-primary column.Can't i set lock if the column in where condition is not a primary key?

```
update tabl1 set col2 = 10 where col3 > 10 and col3 < 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For key range locking SQL Server must use an index to satisfy the range condition so regarding your last query you would need an index on `col3` (and possibly query hints to force its use if the plan does not use it)

Also it does not just lock the specific range in your `WHERE` clause. It locks keys. A range lock on a key protects the range from that key downwards to the next key so the exact range that will be blocked depends upon what keys exist in the index.

More details/links are [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225131/73226)

Comment: But which index should be used?Clustered or non- clustered?

Comment: @wincoding - It makes no difference SQL Server can take key range locks on either as long as it uses that index to resolve the `WHERE`