# SQL Serializable, but avoiding insert locks that wouldn't conflict

Tags: sql-server

Consider this table and two concurrent queries:

```
create table BLARG (a int not null unique);
```

Connection #1:

```
set transaction isolation level snapshot;
begin transaction;
if exists (select 1 from BLARG with (serializable) where a=1) print 'DIE!';
```

Connection #2:

```
set transaction isolation level snapshot;
begin transaction;
insert into BLARG values (2); -- Blocked!
```

Why does inserting a=*2* block a serializable read looking for a=*1*?

In snapshot isolation, is there another way to prevent insertion into a table?

...

In case I've overgeneralized or am not asking a precisely correct question, here's my (slightly less generalized but still generalized) scenario:

Tables [Parts] and [Completed] each have column "Txid"

For any Txid, inserts to [Parts] can be done until a [Completed] record is created, enforced by a [Parts] insert trigger along the lines of "if exists (select 1 from Completed where Txid=...) throw".

Inserting to [Completed] causes the [Parts] table to be summarized and results go somewhere else

All transactions begin in Snapshot isolation

If 2 transactions begin, then one inserts to [Completed] and one inserts to [Parts], the write skew would make the [Completed] trigger miss the insert to [Parts] which happened in the concurrent transaction.

But [Completed] is a very busy table and would rather not use the Serializable isolation if it's going to prevent ALL inserts, when only an insert with a matching Txid is problematic.

Is there a more optimum solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Why insert TSQL statement block when transaction isolation level for another transaction is serializable with non-conflicting filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211605/why-insert-tsql-statement-block-when-transaction-isolation-level-for-another-tra?rq=1)

(Finally found it on another stack question, grr)

Answer:  The initial example only didn't work because the table was empty.